# Joist hanger too low?

Tags: framing, floor, joists, construction, engineering

[image]
[image]

I'm in the process of replacing the joists in a room in my 100 year old house (original members were too far gone with termite damage to do sistering). Original joists were true 2x8s with a 12 foot span - I decided on using 2x10s, but they sit below the 6x8 beam. Should I have used a different hanger instead of this one? (Truss hanger?) That bottom nail seems pretty low. Of course I'm using the Simpson 3.5" 16d into the beam face and 3" 10d nail into the 45° holes.

Comment: Unless it's an optical illusion, I can't tell what is happening from the pic, because it sure looks like the new joist goes through the old one, not butting up to it, as I would have expected?

Comment: They had originally notched the joists to fit into the also-notched  beam. I made a relief notch in the new joists as well, but the full 2x10 is sitting on the hangers, extending around 1/8" past the end of the hanger

Comment: Can we get a photo from a different angle it looks you installed the hanger on the wrong board.

Comment: Not sure what the deal is with posting images, but here's the imgur link:

https://imgur.com/Vo4qbmj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks for the extra pic. I'll be honest, it looks like a lot of weight for that particular style of joist hanger. If it was my job I'd drill at least one extra hole higher up in the hanger to reinforce that lowest one.

One caveat, this counts as 'modifying' the hanger, rendering the manufacturers specs/guarantee etc. void (probably). I'd be talking to the building inspector or even the hanger manufacturer to be safe.

The hangers we have in my area have loads of holes...

You could up the specs of the cross nails by changing them to long construction screws...

Comment: Thank you for your advice.